# Can you use id and href at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I'm obviously a newbie and I'm running into a problem when I'm trying to turn text into a link while also naming it with an id.

I'm currently using:

```
<p id="you" <a href="www.google.com">You</a></p>
```

Using google.com to test.

I haven't been able to get the link working though.

I'm trying to ultimately make a button called You where I'll add all the CSS to id="you" but I want the You word to go to a link.

Can I not write it this way?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your opening paragraph tag is unclosed.

```
<p id="you"><a href="www.google.com">You</a></p>
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the block styling the paragraph gives, you can just go with the following.

```
<a id="you" href="www.google.com">You</a>
```

Comment: Can't believe that is really what was asked.. I thought that's just typo in the question.

Comment: @MightyPork not everyone knows how these things work. Sometimes you need to give the OP a break.

Comment: he is a newbie - he says it himself .. give him a break

Comment: what break, I didn't call him names or anything. I'm just surprised.

Comment: Thanks, I should have caught that, it's right there ... I made a save from google dev tools though and could it be there that all the opening tags were altered?  All the <p> <h1> everything is missing that closing >  :o

Comment: I believe `href=www.google.com"` should be `href="www.google.com"`

Answer (score 1):

Sure: `<a href="http://duckduckgo.com" id="you">You</a>`

[You](http://duckduckgo.com)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?
Yes, it works just fine.

```
<a href="link" id="you">you</a>
```